# File manager `sftp://` Connect to Server via proxy

Tags: nautilus, sftp

In the terminal, I can sftp/ssh into a remote machine via proxy by

```bsh
sftp -J user@proxy user@remote
```

How can I do the same in the "Connect to Server" in the File Manager?

[image]

It requires addresses like `sftp://user@remote` and it is not clear to me how to configure the `-J  user@proxy` in there.

Comment: I don't know - however as a workaround I would expect it to apply settings from your ~/.ssh/config file, so you could specify a proxy for the host there

Answer (score 0):

Open you **/etc/ssh/ssh_config** and enable the ProxyCommand.

`ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com`

and change the value according with your environment. All connections will use the proxy.

If you need proxy only on a single host, create `~/.ssh/config` and add custom setting for host

```
Host hostname1
    ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
```

Comment: Wouldn't this make all my ssh connections go over this proxy? I only want to use this specific proxy when I ssh into that specific remote

Comment: Yes, all ssh connections will use proxy. I have changed the answer in order to provide a better solution.